# Regex math path with specific symbols

Tags: c#, regex

for this moment i have strings like this:
`"document.info.userId"` (json property paths) and regex pattern to validate them: `([\w]+\.)+[\w]+$`

but there appear to be string like this: `"document.role#0.id"` (some extra markup for arrays) and they are valid to, but i can't figure out which regexp pattern to use. This index (#0,#1.. etc) can be only before dot, not in a middle of any path part.

I've already tried patterns `([\w#]+\.)+[\w#]+$` and `([\w]+(#\d+)*\.)+[\w]+(#\d+)*$` but they pass invalid paths like this: `test.some#a.hello`

Should pass:

```
"document.role.id"
"document.role.id.and.other.very.long.path.example"
"document.role#0.id"
"document#1.role#0.id"
"document#1.role#0#1.id"
"document#1.role#0#1.id#21" - terrible representation of array in array
```

Should not pass:

```
"document."
"document.role."
".document"
"test.some#a.hello"
"docum#ent.role.id"
"document.role.#id"
"docu#1ment.role.id"
"document.ro#0#1le.id"
```

Comment: added more examples

Comment: Do you have a specification of the syntax? JsonPath is an alternative to your syntax, which is defined as a kind of "XPath for JSON".

Comment: only difference in indexing arrays like this #N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
^\w+(?:#\d+)*(?:\.\w+(?:#\d+)*)*$
```

It starts by checking for a word followed by any number of indexes (`#N`). This can optionally be followed by any number of `.` and the same check again (a word and indexes).

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dF3fF3/1).

Comment: regex101 is for js,php and py

Answer (score 3):

You can add an optional `#[\d]`:

```
^([\w]+(#[\d])*\.)+[\w]+$
       ^^^^^^^^
```

This way, the text `#N`, N being an integer, can or cannot happen.

See it live with some sample input in https://regex101.com/r/mZ3mZ6/2

Taking into account all the samples you later on added:

```
^([\w]+(#[\d]+)*\.)+[\w]+(#[\d]+)*$
```

This way we also check for `#N`, being N any integer (not just one digit) and also allowing the last block to contain such specifier.

See it live in https://regex101.com/r/mZ3mZ6/3 passing all cases.

Comment: this pass: document#1.creati#1onInfo.userId

Comment: Should be `^([\w]+(#[\d])*\.)+[\w]+$`. `*` instead of `?` because it must be able to match multiple occurrences of `#N`, i.e. `#0#1#2`. You also forgot to copy the `^`.

Comment: @aleha I forgot to add `^` which was in the link. Updated.

Comment: @Chrono oh thanks! I thought `#0#1` wouldn't be allowed. Updated with your hints : )

Answer (score 0):

long solution but works:

```
^(\w+(?:(#[\d]+)*)?\.)(\w+(?:(#[\d]+)*)?\.)+(\w+(?:(#[\d]+)*)?)
```